# Установка apk и установка apk из Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, исключения

Описываю проблему. При установке приложения из Android Studio, приложение запускается и продолжает нормально работать. Но если взять приложение из app/build/outputs/apk/app_debug и установить его просто так, то оно отваливается при запуске с ошибками.

```
11634-11634/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster, PID: 11634
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5318)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4850)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4910) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4850) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**Вот build.gradle (app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "10.10 beta"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: А самому то прочитать логи не суждено: *Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/galaxysoftware.minecraftcraftingmaster-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]* - достаточно исчерпывающе написано ведь

Comment: Я прочитал, но не знаю, как это исправить и что конкретно надо сделать. Был бы благодарен, если бы вы смогли объяснить.

Comment: @Иван, покажите gradle файлы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сверху добавил.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не добавлен плагин гугловых сервисов. Добавьте это в самый конец файла `build.gradle (module app)`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Также убедитесь, что в `build.gradle` (без модулей) есть подключение сервисов:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        //ВОТ ЭТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ (строка ниже)
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пишу, как я исправил это:

**1.**
В buld.gradle (Module:app) добавил:

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    ...'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    ...
}`

**2.** Добавил multiDexEnabled true:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    ..,
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

**3.** В манифесте добавил name:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.